# Turn casting / construction into a perfect forwardable function

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding, universal-reference

SSCCE:

```
#include <functional>

using std::function;
using std::forward;

template<typename ToType, typename... FromTypes>
ToType construct(FromTypes&&... fromTypes) {
  return ToType(forward<FromTypes>(fromTypes)...);
}

class Maybe {
public:
  Maybe() : m_value(42.0f) {}

  template<typename Function>
  auto apply(Function function) const -> decltype(function(std::declval<float>())) {
    return function(value());
  }

private:
  float const& value() const {
    return m_value;
  }

  float m_value;
};

int main() {
  Maybe a;

  a.apply(construct<int, float>);

  return 0;
}
```

Gives the error:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘decltype (function(declval<float>())) Maybe::apply(Function) const [with Function = int (*)(float&&); decltype (function(declval<float>())) = int]’:
test.cpp:31:32:   required from here
test.cpp:17:28: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘float&&’ from expression of type ‘const float’
     return function(value());
                            ^
```

From the error message, it's obviously a problem with the fact that `value()` returns a `const&`.

The key point here, is that the type isn't being deduced on line 17, where value is being passed to it.  The type is being assigned when the `construct` function is passed to `apply` on line 31.

I specified the wrong type to the template of `construct`.  `construct<int, float>`.  If I use `construct<int, float const&>` it functions just fine.

However, this is cumbersome and requires knowledge of the implementation of `apply`.  And it will also never ever bind an lvalue, because `T` and `T&&` are different types.  (Because of the lack of type deduction.)

Is there a way to have a function I can pass to another function and have type deduction occur at the site where it is called, so I can have perfect forwarding happen more or less transparently for the callers?  Or is there another way to achieve this end that doesn't leak complexity to the caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
#include <functional>

using std::function;
using std::forward;

template<typename ToType>
class construct
{
public:
  template<typename... FromTypes>
  ToType operator()(FromTypes&&... fromTypes) {
    return ToType(forward<FromTypes>(fromTypes)...);
  }
};

class Maybe {
public:
  Maybe() : m_value(42.0f) {}

  template<typename Function>
  auto apply(Function function) const -> decltype(function(std::declval<float>())) {
    return function(value());
  }

private:
  float const& value() const {
    return m_value;
  }

  float m_value;
};

int main() {
  Maybe a;

  a.apply(construct<int>());

  return 0;
}
```

You only have to specify the type to which you want to convert to which obviously cannot be deduced in the context you have given.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity You're welcome. Additionally if you have no state in `construct` you can even change the `operator()` to a static member function so you won't even need to give a parameter to `apply`, you would only need to supply the type `construct<int>` as a template parameter

Comment: hmm... it looks like attempting to make it static causes an error. (must be a nonstatic member function)

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Give it a name, `operator()` cannot be static